# VueJS + Firebase Auth + Route Guards - sync problem / race condition

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

While integrating Firebase Auth into my Vue app I recently stumbled across the problem where a logged in user on a page refresh will not be recognized as logged in (and therefore redirected to the login page when trying to access a protected route).
This is due to the fact that the inital callback of `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(...)` has not returned before the route guard evaluates the state.

There are several proposed solutions out there none of which seemed clean to me though. The most prominent seems to be to delay the actual mounting of the app by moving `new Vue(...).$mount('#app')` inside the `onAuthStateChanged()` callback.
Since in most cases the initial view will not require the user to be logged in (or might be the Login route itself) there shouldn't be a need to delay the mounting of the entire app until the firebase callback returns.

I think I might have found a better solution but would appreciate some feedback if you can see any problem with this approach or if it can be further improved upon.

Note: I use a Vuex global state store to manage app state.

I initialize the firebase `onAuthStateChanged()` callback in `main.js` in the `created` lifecycle hook of the App component:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  created() {
    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(!this.$store.getters.firebaseInitialized)
        this.$store.commit('firebaseInitialized')
      if (user) {
        if(!this.$store.authenticated || this.$store.getters.loggedInUser.uid != user.uid)
          this.$store.dispatch('logIn', user)
      }
    })
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

The `firebaseInitialized` boolean in the state keeps track of the init state of firebase, is `false` on default and only gets set to `true` by that first `onAuthStateChanged` callback.

Within `router.js` I now create a "polling promise" that checks said `firebaseInitialized` and waits for the init to complete (or timeout) before checking the auth state of the user:

```
function ensureFirebaseIsInitialized() {
  let timeout = 5000;
  let start = Date.now();
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    (function waitForFirebaseInit(){
      if (store.getters.firebaseInitialized) 
        return resolve();
      else if((Date.now() - start) >= timeout) 
        return reject(new Error('Firebase initialize timeout'))
      setTimeout(waitForFirebaseInit, 30);
    })();
  });
}
```

This promise can now be used within the `router.beforeEach`:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    ensureFirebaseIsInitialized().then(() => {
      if(store.getters.authenticated) {
        next()
      }
      else {
        next('/login')
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('firebase not initialized')
      next('/login')
    })
  } 
  else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Is there any problem I'm not aware of with this kind of approach or can it be further improved?

Comment: And did my answer help?

Comment: How did you implement it now? Does this approach work well? Is this your final solution?

Comment: @ValentinGavran I did use this for a while before switching to Auth0, so I'm currently no longer using Firebase.

Comment: @TommyF okey, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In your Router.js File simply add

```
router.beforeEach((to,from,next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth)){
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(!user)
    {
      next({
        path: '/'

      })
    } else {
      next() 
    }
  })}else next()    
})
```

This works for both preventing a page visit and kicks the user out if hes not authorized while he is on the page. I use this myself on one of my websites and had no problems with it so far

Comment: I don't particularly like this approach, since you are actually registering a callback every time a user visits a protected route (and never unsubscribe them by the looks of it?!). It definitely is less code and simpler, so I can see the appeal, but it's not a clean solution I feel.

Comment: @TommyF there is no need to unsubscribe it